# Creating factory functions in a base class, but have them inaccessible if called on one of its subclasses

Tags: c#, function, inheritance

When I have a base class (a `Vehicle`), I often like to give it factory functions for its subclasses to be more expressive. Perhaps I want a factory function that uses the number of wheels, another based on the max budget, or weight, etc.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var vehicle = Vehicle.FromWheels(2);
    }
}

public abstract class Vehicle {
    protected Vehicle () {
        Console.WriteLine("Created Vehicle Base");
    }
    public static Vehicle FromWheels (int wheels) {
        switch (wheels) {
            case 2:
                return new Bike ();
            case 4:
                return new Car ();
        }
        return null; // Throw exception etc
    }
    // FromBudget(), FromWeight(), etc...
}

public class Bike : Vehicle {
    public Bike () {
        Console.WriteLine("Created Bike");
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
    public Car () {
        Console.WriteLine("Created Car");
    }
}
```

It works fine, but since `Car` and `Bike` are subclasses of `Vehicle`, I can also do this:

```
Bike.FromWheels(4);
```

Which makes no sense.

Yes, I could create a factory class `VehicleFactory` like a normal person. That's fine and reasonable - I was just hoping there'd be a way to keep using the style as shown above.

I also thought of overriding the factory functions in the subclasses and throw an exception if they are called, like this:

.

```
public class Bike : Vehicle {
    public Bike () {
        Console.WriteLine("Created Bike");
    }
    public static new Vehicle FromWheels (int wheels) {
        // Throw exception?
        return null;
    }
}
```

But that feels a bit hacky.

Is there a way to create static factory functions in the base class, but have them inaccessible if called on a subclass?

Comment: [`Bike.FromWheels(3)`](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fazub.eu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F04%2Fazub-ti-fly-26-recumbent-trike.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fazub.eu%2F&docid=bCYwdaEFEentvM&tbnid=ls_I0PY1UCH5CM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjplOjM1ZXkAhWQqIsKHTifB6gQMwiaASgPMA8..i&w=1280&h=816&bih=961&biw=1745&q=trike%20bike&ved=0ahUKEwjplOjM1ZXkAhWQqIsKHTifB6gQMwiaASgPMA8&iact=mrc&uact=8) might make sense . Beside that you are tightly coupling your base class with your derived classes - creating a new Vehicle might force you to edit your base class.

Comment: The `static new` approach violates [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)s [Liskovs Subst Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - making this 3/5 wrong (S,O,L) just for SOLIDs guidelines. Making a `VehicleFabricator` that returns an `IVehicle` with 2,3,4,8 wheels might make more sense

Answer (score 1):

No, any class member (static or instance) that can be accessed from outside a base class can also be accessed from it's derived classes.
Also, this design makes no sense - The base class should have no knowledge whatsoever about the classes that derives from it - and the static factory method should not be a part of it.

Seems to me you are mixing the [Factory method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and the [Abstract factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

In the abstract factory design pattern, you have an interface for your factory classes, and a concrete implementation of that interface for each concrete implementation of the business classes.

[You can see a c# demo on Restester.](https://rextester.com/discussion/OVVG4680/The-abstract-factory-design-pattern-implemented-in-c-using-generics-)

Answer (score 0):

I think not. All possible solutions will be "hacky".
The best way is to create a factory-class (maybe as inner class?).